# Converting (and back) discontinuous values to continuous values in Python 2

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of:

`5 10 10 20 50 50 20`

(there are 4 distinguish numbers).

I want to convert them to:

`0 1 1 2 3 3 2`

(then convert back to the original form).

There are tons of ways to do that, but I am not sure what is the best and Pythonic way?

(a way is to generate a set, convert the set to a list, sort the list, then generate output by the sorted list, but I think it is not the best one)

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem. Why do you need to do this? Maybe there's a better approach.

Comment: I have a data like above, and I need to convert it to ``0..n`` to process further.

Comment: A simple function using logic could work. Does it need to be as fast as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested answer by Delgan is O(n^2) due to the nested loops in `back`. This solution is O(n).

An alternative solution is as follows:

```
lst = [5, 10, 10, 20, 50, 50, 20]

# Convert (and build reverse mapping)
mapping = {}
reverse_mapping = {}
conv = []
for i in lst:
    v = mapping.setdefault(i, len(mapping))
    reverse_mapping[v] = i
    conv.append(v)

# Convert back
back = [reverse_mapping[v] for v in conv]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a good problem for make use of [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) methods.

```
from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict

c = count()
dct = defaultdict(lambda: next(c))

lst = [5, 10, 10, 20, 50, 50, 20]

conv = [dct[i] for i in lst]
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2]

back = [k for c in conv for k, v in dct.items() if v == c]
# [5, 10, 10, 20, 50, 50, 20]
```